# python2.7: can't open file '/usr/lib/python2.7/py_compile.py'

Tags: linux, python, apt-get, debian-squeeze, apt

I'm getting lot's of error with apt-get. I've tried to install package manualy but everything seems stucked.

```
mio@vm:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7-minimal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of python2.7-minimal is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aspell-en libkdc2-heimdal libroken18-heimdal aspell libhdb9-heimdal libpython2.7 libtdb1 libasn1-8-heimdal libgssapi3-heimdal tdb-tools libwind0-heimdal libenchant1c2a libtevent0 libhcrypto4-heimdal
  libhx509-5-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libhunspell-1.3-0 libldb1 libheimntlm0-heimdal libaspell15 libkrb5-26-heimdal
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.5-8) ...
python2.7: can't open file '/usr/lib/python2.7/py_compile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing python2.7-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.33+dfsg-1) ...
configured to not write apport reports
[ ok                                  [....] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.
Usage: /etc/init.d/mongod {start|stop|force-stop|restart|force-reload|status}
insserv: warning: script 'mongodb' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `mongodb'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `mongodb'
[FAIL] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Setting up mongodb-10gen (2.4.8) ...
[FAIL] Starting database: mongod failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongodb, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mongodb-10gen (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
configured to not write apport reports
                                      dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal
 mysql-server-5.5
 mongodb-10gen
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

For Python2.7-minimal i've tried

> apt-get install --reinstall python2.7-minimal

Without success. All command like

> apt-get clean
>   apt-get -f install

Return the same.

Any help will be realy appreciated for python, also for other packages too.

Comment: What's the output of 'apt-get check'?

Comment: @rickhg12hs : `> apt-get checkReading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done`

Comment: What's the output of 'apt-get update'?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Hit http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist Release.gpg
Hit ......
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: @rickhg12hs no error on apt-get update

Comment: Strange, but good no errors.  Would you mind doing an 'apt-get upgrade'?

Comment: @rickhg12hs i get nearly the same as on my main question. Finishing with Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal
 mysql-server-5.5
 mongodb-10gen
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: What does 'dpkg -C' show?

Comment: @rickhg12hs `The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 mysql-server         MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the lates`

Comment: @rickhg12hs `The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 mongodb-10gen        An object/document-oriented database
 python2.7-minimal    Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
 mysql-server-5.5     MySQL database server binaries and system database setup`

Comment: @rickhg12hs `The following packages are missing the md5sums control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
 dhcp3-client         ISC DHCP server (transitional package)
 bin86                16-bit x86 assembler and loader
 dhcp3-common         ISC DHCP common files (transitional package)`

Comment: @rickhg12hs but i try to do it one by one with `dpkg --configure <package>` i'm getting exactly the same errors as for `apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Did you try the recommended reinstalls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've nearly found and issue with help found here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1763604&page=3.

Simply doing 
`dpkg -P --force depends <packages who fail>`

More infos about this arguments : http://tipstricks.itmatrix.eu/?p=755

And after install it with aptitude
`sudo aptitude install mysql-server-5.1`

Not the cleanest way, but no more errors !

Answer (score 1):

After ubuntu 16.04 -> 18.04 upgrade I had an issue with pyhon3.7 libs missing, whole apt/dpkg was blocked. Luckily found missing `/usr/lib/python3.7/py_compile.py` one level deeper `/usr/local/lib/python3.7`. Solution which worked for me was backup (rename) whole `/usr/lib/python3.7` and replace with sym-link.

```
Nastavuje se balík python3-tk:amd64 (3.6.5-3) …
(null): can't open file '/usr/lib/python3.7/py_compile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
dpkg: chyba při zpracovávání balíku python3-tk:amd64 (--configure):
 installed python3-tk:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Nastavuje se balík python3-lib2to3 (3.6.5-3) …
(null): can't open file '/usr/lib/python3.7/py_compile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
dpkg: chyba při zpracovávání balíku python3-lib2to3 (--configure):
 installed python3-lib2to3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem with python3.7. Solved with:

```
apt install python3.7
```

No idea why apt couldn't figure this out.